# Динамический диалог на php js ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

Задача такая создать динамический диалог на ajax js и php. Задача вроде выполнена, но при использовании данной функции создается куча запросов ajax, которые грузят систему. Как ограничится только одним запросом в некоторый промежуток времени. Сам php файл не нужен проблема только с js(ajax)

```
function show () { 
  var form_data = $(".form").serialize();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST", 
    url: "go.php", 
    data: form_data,
    success: function (y) {
      $('.news').empty();
      $('.news').append(y);
    }
  });
}

function hoho () {
  clearInterval(ff);  
  var ff = setInterval('show()',1000);
}

hoho();
```

Answer (score 1):

Вызывайте `show` в следующий раз не раньше, чем вернется ответ на запрос из предыдущего вызова.

```
function show() { 
  var form_data = $(".form").serialize();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST", 
    url: "go.php", 
    data: form_data,
    success: function(y) {
      $('.news').html(y);
      setTimeout(show, 1000);
    }
  });
}

show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Интервал делай больше. Последний параметр функции SetInterval и есть твой промежуток времени.

```
var ajax_interval = setInterval(function(){
     var form_data = $(".form").serialize();
     $.ajax({
            type: "POST", 
            url: "go.php", 
            data: form_data,
            success: function (y) {
      $('.news').empty();
      $('.news').append(y);

            }
        });
}, 1000);
```